# Why does this program not swap the first and last item of the input list?

Tags: python

Let `A=[1,2,3,4]`. I want to write a program that interchanges the first and last items of the list (so `A` becomes `[4,2,3,1]`). My attempt at this is the following:

```
def swap(l):
   m=[]
   m=m+[l[len(l)-1]]+l[1:len(l)-1]+[l[0]]
   l=m
```

If I then check the value of `A` after running `swap(A)`, then `A=[1,2,3,4]` still. Why?

Comment: Well you can do `A[0], A[-1] = A[-1], A[0]` to swap the first and last element. No need to write this complicated code.

Comment: The reason is because [parameters are passed by "value", and not by reference](https://robertheaton.com/2014/02/09/pythons-pass-by-object-reference-as-explained-by-philip-k-dick/).

Comment: Yes, I know that one can do that. The point of this question is to comprehend the reason that Python does not like this particular code. The logic makes perfect sense to me but Python isn't having it.

Comment: `l` and `m` are purely local variables. `l = m` just reassigns `l` to point to `m` which is  locally allocated and has to reference to the caller's list. You could use `l[:] = m` but yeah, this code is pretty roundabout as others have mentioned.

Comment: @enzo python does not use call by value, as that very link explains

Comment: @TuoTuo is simple. `m=m+[l[len(l)-1]]+l[1:len(l)-1]+[l[0]]` create a new list object and assigns it to the local variable `m`. (I have no idea why you are doing `m = []`, it is totally pointless). Then, you assign that list being referenced by `m` to *another* local variable, `l`. The function terminates, and doesn't return anything. Why do you *expect* `A` to change at all? You never mutated the object you passed in (which is generally good), but you returned no data.

Comment: The `l` you assign within the function now points to the expression you created with `m`. At that point, the input `l` variable is not pointing to the same object you passed in. I think you can do something like l[:] = m to replace all elements in the original `l`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga That's why I put two goddamn QUOTATION MARKS around the value.

Comment: @enzo yeah, *don't do that*. Because potentially thousands of people will read that comment and take away "Python is pass by value".

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga The reason I put a link is to exactly avoid that, so people can understand why I said this. If people take their conclusion reading a comment and not the link it's pointing to, so that's their problem, not mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code actually works fine. It may be the fact that you never return the new value of `A` in your function.

```
def swap(l):
   m=[]
   m=m+[l[len(l)-1]]+l[1:len(l)-1]+[l[0]]
   l=m
   #return new value
   return l
   
A=[1,2,3,4]
#store swaped value of A
A = swap(A)
print(A)
```

Another option would be to use `global`, though I wouldn't use it over `return`.

```
def swap():
    global A
    A = [A[len(A)-1]]+A[1:len(A)-1]+[A[0]]
    
A=[1,2,3,4]
swap()
```

outputs

```
[4, 2, 3, 1]
```

Also, if you are accepting of a shorter and much cleaner way.

```
def swap(l):
    l[0],l[-1] = l[-1],l[0]
    return l
A = swap([1,2,3,4])
```

Comment: It's sort of odd to `return l` in the bottom code. It's already been mutated in-place, so the normal protocol is to return None, as Python does with `.sort()`. Returning the list implies it's a fresh allocation, which could lead to confusing bugs for the caller if they didn't realize the original list was also being mutated. Generally, swapping is an in-place operation for performance reasons. Also, `l` is a frowned-upon variable name by PEP-8 because it's too similar to `i` and `1`. The middle strategy using `global` should not be suggested, it's non idempotent and brittle.

Comment: This may be a dumb question, but why do I have to return l in my code? If I define A before hand, other code I have seen for this changes A automatically. And yes, I am accepting of a shorter and much cleaner way (I can read the internet as well), but the point here is that I am trying to get a better understanding of how Python works.

Comment: well, when you pass in a variable to a function, in a magical world a new variable is created. You mess with that variable. Then now what? The variable outside the function has not changed, just the magical var inside. So if return this magical variable, we can store it in another variable. Goddam, I'll never become a teacher. Look [here](https://realpython.com/python-return-statement/) for some real advice

Answer (score 0):

I've seen the other solutions, and I think your intent was to have the function work in-place. I think if this is the case, then the `return` statements defeat this. And the operation is just a swap, so this is my suggestion:

```
def swap(l):
    l[0], l[-1] = l[-1], l[0]
```

This operates on the list and modifies it in place. Of course, it has to be in a variable.

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4]
swap(l)
print(l)
[4, 2, 3, 1]
```

Comment: I know it's what @BuddyBob put in his final solution, but my approach is that the OP had thought swap would modify the argument directly, so there is no return.

Answer (score -1):

When you pass a list or dictionary to a function in python, it is passed by reference. So if u mutate the variable "l" then the original list will also mutate. But here you are assigning a new value to "l", but not mutating. The variable "l" has a reference to the original list, but the not original list itself. So when you change its value the reference to the original list is gone.

Comment: Forget all this "pass by reference" and "pass by value" if you're working with Python. You pass the object. That's it.

Comment: No *python never uses pass by reference** if what you said *were* true then the OPs function would work! Python uses neither call by value not call by reference, and the evaluation strategy **never depends on the type**

Answer (score -1):

Here is a function that inverses the list. It works by inserting the elements into the first position in the list one by one:

```
A=[1,2,3,4]

def swap(list):
    swapped = []
    for num in list:
        swapped.insert(0, num)
    return swapped

print(swap(A))
```